# CCK taxonomy field value lost when doing feed importing

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 6, feeds

Drupal CCK taxonomy field value lost when doing feed importing

In Drupal 6, CCK lost taxonomy when doing feeds import.

Have a content type "Thesis".
It has a field taxonomy "Category".

For example, have this thesis, in Physics category
Thesis: Investigations on Inductively Coupled Plasma Interaction
Category: Physics

Have this thesis, in Chemistry category
Thesis: Layer-by-Layer Self-Assembled Thin Films
Category: Chemistry

Create feed import to import and parse xml to load this content type.
Select update existing content.

When doing feed import, somehow the taxonomy field value is lost.

For example, have this thesis, in Physics category
Thesis: Investigations on Inductively Coupled Plasma Interaction
Category: VALUE LOST HERE <<<<<<<<<<==========================================

Have this thesis, in Chemistry category
Thesis: Layer-by-Layer Self-Assembled Thin Films
Category: VALUE LOST HERE <<<<<<<<<<==========================================